# File loop not pulling the referenced worksheet range in normal code

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have written a code in my personalxlsb file that automatically pulls in reports from a website using a webquery. The code (listed directly below) works great when I open each excel workbook individually and run the code. z,x, and y refernce a value on Sheet1 for each workbook (they are vlookups to other data). I have looked and looked and cant find a solution. thanks for any help in advance!

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
z = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1").Value
y = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$2").Value
x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$3").Value

For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name = "ATB by Branch" Then
With Worksheets("ATB by Branch").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://pe.---.com/---/clients/---" & y & "/amr/amr" & z & "/tb01" & x _
    , Destination:=Worksheets("ATB by Branch").Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "tb0120130903110631ash"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwrtiteCells
    .SavePassword = True
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
End With

ElseIf ws.Name = "ATB by Ins by Sum" Then
```

The problem is when i attempt to run this code for each file (listed below) in a folder the code ceases to pull in the data and I suspect the issue is that the z,y, and x variables are no longer pulling the correct values.

```
Dim wkbOpen As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String

MyPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\tlear\Desktop\Copy of VBA Physician Files\"
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    Set wkbOpen = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & MyFile)
    With wkbOpen


Dim ws As Worksheet
z = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1").Value
y = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$2").Value
x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$3").Value

For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name = "ATB by Branch" Then
With Worksheets("ATB by Branch").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://pe.----.com/---/clients/----" & y & "/amr/amr" & z & "/tb01" & x _
    , Destination:=Worksheets("ATB by Branch").Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "tb0120130903110631ash"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwrtiteCells
    .SavePassword = True
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
 End With
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: try prefixing the sheets objects with `wkbOpen` like `z = wknopen.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value`

Comment: mehow, I attempted your suggestion but to no avail. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this proper formatted, you missed some `.` within the `With` blocks. This compiles fine but i cannot test. Just curious do you need to close them at the end?

```
Sub SO_18897512()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    MyPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\tlear\Desktop\Copy of VBA Physician Files\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls")

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & MyFile)
            Z = .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1").Value
            y = .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$2").Value
            x = .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$3").Value

            For Each ws In .Worksheets
                If ws.Name = "ATB by Branch" Then
                    With ws.QueryTables.Add( _
                        Connection:= "URL;https://pe.----.com/---/clients/----" & y & "/amr/amr" & Z & "/tb01" & x , _
                        Destination:=ws.Range("$A$1"))
                        .Name = "tb0120130903110631ash"
                        .FieldNames = True
                        .RowNumbers = False
                        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                        .PreserveFormatting = True
                        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                        .BackgroundQuery = True
                        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwrtiteCells
                        .SavePassword = True
                        .SaveData = True
                        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                        .RefreshPeriod = 0
                        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
                        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
                        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
                        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
                        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
                        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
                        .WebDisableRedirections = False
                        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
                    End With
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: PatricK, thank you so much for your response, unfortunately your suggestions didnt remedy the issue... I just dont understand why the code runs perfectly when its ran outside of the loop and not within the loop...Any more help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you try Delete the QueryTable entry before Add? I don't have a valid URL to test. And may need to clear the `ws.Range("A1")` too.